# C# Web Service for Upload File gives Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, internal-server-error

I have a Web Service application written in C#. I want it to handle a basic request, namely, from a form, it should get file name and file content and save it to Web Service's working directory.
The code is:

```
[WebMethod]
    public void PutFile(byte[] buffer, string filename)
    {
        BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(Server.MapPath(filename), FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite));
        binWriter.Write(buffer);
        binWriter.Close();
    }
```

When I invoke it by running xsp in the directory of .asmx file, I can use other Web Services, such as add two numbers, etc. However when I invoke PutFile method, I get following error

> 500 - Internal Server Error
>   System.ArgumentException: WebChangeTypeFailed
>   Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

And follows some function errors.

I am new for developing Web Service applications using .NET and I am not sure about the cause of this problem. I've looked at web.config file and I didn't notice something strange. web.config file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="C#" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
    </customErrors>
    <authentication mode="None">
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <httpHandlers>
    </httpHandlers>
    <trace enabled="false" localOnly="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="10" traceMode="SortByTime" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
    <pages>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone help ? Thanks.

Comment: Does your app have write permission for that directory?

Comment: @S.Petrosov yes it has. However I don't think that is the cause. Because it gives error when I simply return, without executing a statement. I think the problem is related with function parameters.

Comment: it would help if you had source file name and line number with the exception. or at least more of the call stack. run a debug build and try to pinpoint the location. how large is the file?

Comment: @user3035291 can you please share the code of this function's call

Comment: I think you need to set the appropriate attribute for the web method. You can look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @dlatikay currently, file is not too big. a few lines approximately. but I am planning to send a file approximately 100MB for later steps.

Comment: @S.Petrosov sure(http://pastebin.com/5bfcnxiV)

Comment: @user3035291 i think the reason of the error is here
form.AddBinaryData ( "buffer", fileCon, "as", "text/xml");
You should submit binary data instead of "text/xml" ,should not you?

Comment: @S.Petrosov no this is not the problem. It implies it will be saved as xml file. Nothing to do with the content I've sent. Also as I said, even if I don't run the caller side, in the default page of such a web service, it still gives error. (http://imgur.com/zZ5Ff9Z) and (http://imgur.com/FRqVR8F)

Comment: the second screenshot reveals that it receives http header values which are expected to be numbers but ain't (in `UrlParameterReader.Read`). what does the full request query string look like?
.

Comment: @dlatikay simple characters. First i tried to send them as converted format to base64, however it didn't work